# Is there the equivalent of the WP plugin Types for Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

So I have a Drupal 7 client who needs to have a dynamic content type...

name, description, 3 images

We will show these "objects" (for lack of a better word) in a filterable grid. Also, the client needs to be able to add, update and delete these on their own.

I have done this sort of thing many times in WordPress with the plugin called "Types" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/).

Is there an equivalent plugin for Drupal 7? If not, any thoughts as to how I would go about this?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great advantages of using Drupal is that it is a framework for creating custom content types very easily using the administrative interface. See this for further reference and good luck!

http://m.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-and-theming-custom-content-type-drupal-7

Comment: Wonderful...that looks like what I needed. I had some trouble with the mobile link so if anyone needs the desktop one here it is: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-and-theming-custom-content-type-drupal-7